# Discord Bot in Python. Playing two audio files at once

Tags: python, audio, bots, playback, discord

I've been trying to make my bot play short audio file while playing other, music. I had no success.

I have tried to use the `play_audio` function while playing using `create_ffmpeg_player` for playing the other audio file but `play_audio` just makes a crashing sound and doesn't play the audio file.

```
async def cmd_noise(self, message):
    vc = message.author.voice_channel
    voice_client = await self.get_voice_client(vc)
    voice_client.play_audio('other/Qoo.mp3')
```

Is there is even a way to make a Discord bot play 2 audio files at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way with ffmpeg to play 2 audio files at once. You could only make another Bot which plays the wanted sounds.